# Extending the default ASP.NET MVC3 membership system

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a new web app that makes use of the default membership system in ASP.NET MVC3.

However, what should I do if want to start storing additional information about these registered users?

Supposing I wanted to store each users "fav colour", what is the best practice in this sitution?

I did look at the suggested "related questions" but found these were more geared towards webforms or maybe just at a level I could not understand...

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I typically create a table in my database to hold this additional information and use the username (must be unique) form the membership db as the key.

Comment: +1 You could try using the profile system to store data, but I've found it gets to be a giant pain to manage. Making your own table is the way to go.. you can also key it on the membership id GUID if over the username. In theory usernames could change, but the GUIDs will never change.

Answer (score 3):

using the built in membership system for profiles is a giant pain with mvc the way i usually work around this is creating my own table and adding an entry with the assigned user guid as a key on user registration and attaching to the membership class using extension methods or a wrapper